# Systemsetup SetBoot equivalent for Windows and Mac? Formerly known as Bless?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, boot-camp, reboot, osx-el-capitan

I run a couple of computer labs at a university that dual boot into Mac OSX and Windows. Years ago, I used to be able to run a `bless -setBoot` command from Apple Remote Desktop to start up an entire classroom on one platform or the other, both scheduled and on demand.

We used to us commands like bless on the Mac side: `bless -mount /Volumes/ -setBoot shutdown -r now`

And then we were able to script the Windows side with stuff like this: `C:\Program Files\Boot Camp\bootcamp.exe" -StartupDisk "Macintosh HD" Shutdown /r /t 0`

However, this stopped working sometime around Mavericks (maybe because the name of the boot volume seemed to randomly be either "EFI Boot" or "Macintosh HD").

I've been researching this a lot, and came across how `bless` is depreciated and I should use `systemsetup` after disabling `csrutil`. (You can't even `-liststartupdisks` without disabling `csrutil`!)

So if I list the startup disks: `sudo systemsetup -liststartupdisks`

I get this:

> /Volumes/.BOOTCAMP/WINDOWS /System/Library/CoreServices

However, trying to set Windows as the startup disk doesn't work: `sudo systemsetup -setstartupdisk /Volumes/.BOOTCAMP/WINDOWS`

It returns:

> Not a System Folder: /Volumes/.BOOTCAMP/WINDOWS/System/Library/CoreServices

I AM able to boot into Windows 8.1 Pro and Mac OS 10.11.6 by holding down <kbd>option</kbd> and restarting... and also the Recovery partition (why isn't that listed?)

I'm thinking about buying something like Boot Runner to manage the labs, but it doesn't have the sort of command line control via ARD and VNC that I'd like to have. Has anyone found a setBoot workaround for El Capitan?